# How to consume Alfresco APIs from an angular application?

Tags: angular, alfresco

I have an angular application, and I want to interact with Alfresco community 7.1 via APIs from this [List](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/) . how can I call these APIs?

Another question, I know that is possible to integrate ADF with angular applications, is there any tutorial or guide on how-to ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to build a service that makes HTTP calls using HttpModule. Below is an example your service.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlfrescoService  {
baseUrl="/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1";
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getActionDefinitions(): Observable<any> {
  const specificRoute="/action-definitions?skipCount=0&maxItems=100";
  return this.http.get(baseUrl+specificRoute).pipe(
    map(res=>res)
  );
}
```

in your angular component you need to inject your service and subscrib to the function.

```
constructor(private alfrescoService  : AlfrescoService  ) {}

loadData(){
  this.alfrescoService.getActionDefinitions().subscribe({
    next:res=>{
      console.log(res)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late replay, and thank you for your response.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I got the 401 Unauthorized eroor, so I guess I need to implement the auth services first, any suggestions please!

Comment: if you are getting 401 that's a good start it means that you did it right. now for the auth it works the same way:
you need the auth URL and the credentials to make the auth call. but then it depends you either get an auth token to send with your requests or something else. I don't know alfresco so I can't know their auth mode auth, oauth, oauth2, etc...

Comment: thank you so much, I will try to find out more about alfresco auth

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to interact with Alfresco API with an Angular Application :**

I would suggest you generate an angular client from the OpenAPI Defintion of Alfresco webservices :

```
npm install @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli -g
openapi-generator-cli generate -g typescript-angular -i https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/definitions/alfresco-auth.yaml -o /<PATH_TO_OUTPUT>/
```

The Alfresco yaml are here :

- authentication : https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/definitions/alfresco-auth.yaml
- core : https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/definitions/alfresco-core.yaml
- search : https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/definitions/alfresco-search.yaml

Then, use the generated services to get a ticket from the authentication API, and then use the APIs you need.

**If you want a link to some ADF documentation and in particular howtos**

I would suggest you to look at the official documentation :
**https://www.alfresco.com/abn/adf/docs/tutorials/creating-your-first-adf-application/**

Comment: The http calls works fine, but I will try this method too, Thank you,